# Network different than defined name after docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-network

Well I try to create a network of several dockers in a single compose file, however the network that should be created isn't there, even while `docker-compose up` runs fine:

docker compose:

```
networks:
  allsports.test:
    driver: bridge
services:
  allsports.test.nginx:
    build:
      context: ./allsports.test.nginx/
    container_name: allsports.test.nginx
    image: allsports.test.nginx
    networks:
    - allsports.test
    ports:
    - 380:80
    restart: on-failure
  allsports.test.redis:
    build:
      context: ./allsports.test.redis/
    container_name: allsports.test.redis
    image: allsports.test.redis
    networks:
    - allsports.test
    restart: on-failure
version: '3.7'
```

After running `docker-compose up -d`:

```
Starting allsports.test.nginx ... done
Starting allsports.test.redis ... done
```

However now I try to inspect the network: `sudo docker inspect allsports.app` says that the network is not existing.
If I do `sudo docker network ls` I'm also not seeing the network.

If I check one of the created dockers:

```
sudo docker inspect allsports.test.nginx -f "{{.NetworkSettings.Networks}}"

> map[allsportstest_allsports.test:0xc000604000]
```

What causes this renaming and (how) can I logically find the actual networks created by inspecting the compose file?

Comment: Hi... check the dot notation in service file... and for network names... may be that causing the issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default `docker` names created by `docker-compose` are using the compose project name as a prefix to avoid naming conflicts.

The project name is by default the name of the folder containing your `docker-compose.yml`. You can customize it through the [`COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME` environment variable](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/envvars/#compose_project_name) (in your shell or in a `.env` file) or with the [`-p` command line option](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/overview/)

The way the default `docker` names are calculated depends on the type of object. For example, default containers names are created from the pattern `<projectName>_<serviceIdentifier>_<containerIncrement>`. But you can usually use you own custom name when needed (as you did in your above compose file by naming your unique services containers).

For networks, the default name is `<projectName>_<networkIdentifier>` as reported by your last inspect command in your question. So you can definitely infer that name from the compose project name and the network identifier in your file.

Meanwhile, as with you containers, you can use the [network `name` option](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#name-1) to configure you own custom name that will be used as is. In that case, you must take care of potential naming conflicts by yourself.

```
networks:
  allsports.test:
    driver: bridge
    name: allports.test
```